# Magento 2: Getting error Unsupported image format. File: /var/www/mysite/pub/media//Meeting_notes_2__1.docx

Tags: magento2, image-upload

I am getting an error in admin editor:

> Unsupported image format. File:
>   /var/www/clients/mysite/pub/media//Meeting_notes_2__1.docx

My Code is

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                        <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <preference for="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Model\Cms\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage" />
```

Comment: You get this error because of you have defined Type for Image (`Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage`) and  pass argument item for `docx`  You can see in magento core file`/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml` there is no such a file type extension for you given Type.

Comment: Using the above code what do you want to achieve? what do you want to do?

Comment: @chirag I have updated my code. Can you please check and suggest the solution for this

Comment: Why you are pass `<item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>` what do you want? do you want file upload functionality in admin or frontend form?

Comment: @ChiragPatel I need upload funtionality for Wysiwyg editor in magento2 admin.

Comment: @Siwani see my answer, it's work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to pass **docx** file extension to `<item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">` and `<item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">` try with below way it's working for me in **Magento 2.3.1**.

> app/code/[Company]/[Module]/etc/di.xml

Add below code.

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <preference for="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage" type="[Company]\[Module]\Model\Cms\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage" />
```

create Storage.php file at below path.

> app/code/[Company]/[Module]/Model/Cms/Wysiwyg/Images/Storage.php

```
    <?php

namespace [Company]\[Module]\Model\Cms\Wysiwyg\Images;

class Storage extends \Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage
{
    public function uploadFile($targetPath, $type = null)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader $uploader */
        $uploader = $this->_uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
        $allowed = $this->getAllowedExtensions($type);
        if ($allowed) {
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions($allowed);
        }
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
        $result = $uploader->save($targetPath);

        if (!$result) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('We can\'t upload the file right now.'));
        }

        // Change Start
        if (strtolower($uploader->getFileExtension()) !== 'docx' && strtolower($uploader->getFileExtension()) !== 'pdf') {
            // Create Thumbnail
            $this->resizeFile($targetPath . '/' . $uploader->getUploadedFileName(), true);
        }

        $result['cookie'] = [
            'name' => $this->getSession()->getName(),
            'value' => $this->getSession()->getSessionId(),
            'lifetime' => $this->getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
            'path' => $this->getSession()->getCookiePath(),
            'domain' => $this->getSession()->getCookieDomain(),
        ];

        return $result;
    }
}
```

> Run **php bin/magento cache:clean**

Then Go to **Admin > Content > Page > Edit or Add new page**  Inside content click on insert image and upload **docx** file

I hope it helps!

Comment: I did already same for Pdf. This is working for pdf file but need to enable also for doc and docx file in editor

Comment: Just copy and paste my code, I have just test now it's working. And let me know.

Comment: Okay let me check and update you

Comment: Your code is working fine. you need to update one thing. If you are adding this line ---- <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>-- for pdf then you need to add pdf in this condition if (strtolower($uploader->getFileExtension()) !== 'pdf') .. Please update your comment. ------------------>Also add for docx file with this way <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item> and add condition like this if (strtolower($uploader->getFileExtension()) !== 'docx' && strtolower($uploader->getFileExtension()) !== 'pdf')

Comment: Ohhh, sorry it is a typo mistake. I have updated my answer. see and you can accept the answer so it will usefull for other users :) Thanks.

Comment: Great! you can also up-vote to my above comment whatever you can

Comment: Sure! +1 for your comment & good question :)

Answer (score 2):

Please Look at here,

Please change this file

> project/vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml

Add any extension you want to add `<item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>`

```
<argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
<item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>
</item>
<item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>
</item>
<item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
    <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>
</item>
```

Comment: This is not working.. already tried it

Comment: Check my updated code.

Comment: what you have updated in this code?

Comment: In second add <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
add this line :-     <item name="docx" xsi:type="number">1</item>

Comment: This is adding doc and docx file but showing error. I am not able to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Please see my updated code.....

Comment: I have updated my code.  But still not working. Please check my updated comment

Comment: Please can u see your error , there ia s double // slash after media 


    Unsupported image format. File: /var/www/clients/mysite/pub/media//Meeting_notes_2__1.docx

Comment: Yes this is the same. Double slash is coming.